Positioning Multiple Fading Titles with Tikzpagenodes
The following code is adapted from the answer posted by hpekristiansen in   Giving a Title a Gilded Effect:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
%\usepackage[hmargin=0.7in, vmargin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[hmargin=0in,vmargin=0in,paperwidth=4.375in,paperheight=7.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfornament,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{gold}{RGB}{215,190,105}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{1,50,32}
\usepackage{yfonts}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myborder, color=transparent!0, inner sep=0.4cm]
    \node[below right] at (current page text area.north west) {\pgfornament[width=3cm]{63}};
    \node[below left ] at (current page text area.north east) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=v]{63}};
    \node[above right] at (current page text area.south west) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=h]{63}};
    \node[above left ] at (current page text area.south east) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=c]{63}};
    \node[below] at (current page text area.north) {\pgfornament[width=4.3cm, symmetry=h]{71}};
    \node[above] at (current page text area.south) {\pgfornament[width=4.3cm]{71}};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=mytext, color=transparent!0]
    \node (n) at (current page text area) {\swabfamily{\scalebox{5}{Gilded}}};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=mytext2, color=transparent!0]
    \node (n) at (current page text area) {\swabfamily{\scalebox{4}{More Gilded}}};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}


\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \fill[darkgreen] (current page text area.south west) rectangle (current page text area.north east);
        \fill[path fading=myborder, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, transform canvas={xshift=1pt, yshift=-1pt}] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
        \fill[path fading=myborder, fit fading=false, fading 
        transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=gold] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
        \fill[path fading=mytext  , fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, transform canvas={yshift=-2.75pt}]  (n.south west) rectangle (n.north east);
        \fill[path fading=mytext  , fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=gold] (n.south west) rectangle (n.north east);
        
        %\fill[path fading=mytext2  , fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, transform canvas={yshift=-2.75pt}]  (n.south west) rectangle (n.north east);
        %\fill[path fading=mytext2  , fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=gold] (n.south west) rectangle (n.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

with the output

QUESTION: (i) How may I print the "Gilded" title, say, about an inch higher than where it is currently; and (ii) How may I print the mytext2 title ("More Gilded") slightly below it?
Remark: If I uncomment out the last two lines of code immediately prior to \end{tikzpicture} and run it, one title is merely superimposed on the other at the center of the page.
Thank you.

The easiest way to do this is to use a single fading. Several of the commands in your actual picture were not having any effect anyway. (I counted three.)
It's also a little bit more manageable if you use font size commands, even though it won't get you all the way without \scalebox or some in-house transformation.
So, maybe something like this?

\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0in,vmargin=0in,paperwidth=4.375in,paperheight=7.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfornament,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{gold}{RGB}{215,190,105}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{1,50,32}
\usepackage{yfonts}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myborder, color=transparent!0, inner sep=0.4cm]
  \node[below right] at (current page text area.north west) {\pgfornament[width=3cm]{63}};
  \node[below left ] at (current page text area.north east) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=v]{63}};
  \node[above right] at (current page text area.south west) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=h]{63}};
  \node[above left ] at (current page text area.south east) {\pgfornament[width=3cm, symmetry=c]{63}};
  \node[below] at (current page text area.north) {\pgfornament[width=4.3cm, symmetry=h]{71}};
  \node[above] at (current page text area.south) {\pgfornament[width=4.3cm]{71}};
  \node [anchor=south] (n) at ([yshift=5pt]current page text area) {\swabfamily{\Huge\scalebox{2}{Gilded}}};
  \node [anchor=north]  at ([yshift=-5pt]current page text area) {\large\scalebox{2}{\swabfamily{More Gilded}}};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{document}
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \fill[darkgreen] (current page text area.south west) rectangle (current page text area.north east);
    \fill[path fading=myborder, fit fading=false, fading 
    transform={shift=(current page.center)}, ball color=gold] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

It really does not make sense to use a canvas transform unless desperate because it causes pgf to lose track of everything. In a case like this, where you're relying on it keeping track of things, it's not going to work.

I regret that I didn't notice this before--but what happened to the metallic effects in the ornaments  of the MWE? I didn't want those to be negated.

@DDS You mean because your shading has a steeper gradient so they're darker at the bottom, for example? I assume it is some artefact of the way pgf handles shadings. There will be a difference between applying the same shading to two areas separately and applying it across both. That is, I assumed it was to do with the ball shading rather than the fading?
